# How stream json content from jackson to org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity?

Tags: java, json, stream, inputstream, outputstream

I am trying to stream json with base64 into elasticsearch which uses [Appache HttpComponents](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOmYX3isjWAhVhCpoKHWqdB_UQFggrMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhc.apache.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNEhuj1f1q8hjbLVAapS3uCzjkjQ9w) (as I understand).

For json stream I created `JsonGenerator`, but it needs "some" `OutputStream`. For sending request via Jest it is needed to create `InputStreamEntity` from "some" `InputStream`. So `JsonGenerator` needs stream for writing and `InputStreamEntity` stream for reading (`unknowOutputStream` and `unknowInputStream` variables). The stream (as I understand) should be the same - but how create it?

At first glance I could use something like `ByteArrayInputStream` but with that I loose streaming because it will populate content into `byte[]` so all stream data will be stored into memory. How create a stream which will store only a piece of data until this data is read. And then hold another piece of data?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;

import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Exmaple {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        final InputStream inputStream;
        final int size;

        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("myHost", 443, "https")).build();

        final OutputStream unknowOutputStream;
        final InputStream unknowInputStream;


        final JsonGenerator generator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(unknowOutputStream);
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeFieldName("content");
        generator.writeBinary(inputStream, size);
        generator.writeEndObject();


        restClient.performRequest(
                "POST",
                "somepath",
                Collections.emptyMap(), new InputStreamEntity(unknowInputStream));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a solution using a [PipedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) / PipedOutputStream from the JDK, but I guess it would be simpler for you to swicth from `InputStreamEntity` to `EntityTemplate` in HTTPClient's API.

[`EntityTemplate`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/EntityTemplate.html) is a HTTP Entity that works with a `ContentProducer`, and the only method of the `ContentProducer` is `writeTo(OutputStream)`. In this way, you would not have to bridge Input and Output Streams.

```
new EntityTemplate(new ContentProducer(
    (outputStream) -> {
        final JsonGenerator generator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(outputStream);
        generator.write(...);
    }
));
```

(You might want to create subclasses, properly deal with exceptions, ... instead of using a lambda. I used one for simplicity).